# Add item to comma separated list with one-liner

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

I want to add a new item to a string variable which represents a comma-separated list while preventing to have items twice.

I came up with this python solution:

```
python -c "import sys ; first = set(sys.argv[1].split(',')) ; all = first.union(set(sys.argv[2:])) ; print ','.join(all)" 1,2 4 3 2
1,3,2,4
```

In multiple lines:

```
import sys
first = set(sys.argv[1].split(','))
all = first.union(set(sys.argv[2:]))
print ','.join(all)
```

While the solution works, it is not pretty well suited for a one-liner in a shell script.

I've tried a couple of things using `awk`, `sed` or plain `bash` but nothing lead to a short but still stable solution. Does anybody has an idea how to express that with a short command line idiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `bash` option: Keep your list of items in a string variable (`list` below) with leading and trailing commas.  That way every item begins and ends with a comma, which makes things much easier.  To add an item:

```
new_item=42   # or whatever
list="${list//,${new_item},/,}${new_item},"
```

The `${list//...}` removes any duplicates (`//` means global replacement), then the `${new_item},` pastes the new item onto the end of the list.  To add multiple items:

```
list=",1,2,"
for x in 4 3 2 ; do list="${list//,$x,/,}$x," ; done
```

To strip the commas off the list, you can use

```
list="${list#,}"
list="${list%,}"
```

A one-liner for your specific example above, but extended with more test cases, would be:

```
bash -c 'list=",$1,"; shift; for f in "$@"; do list="${list//,$f,/,}$f,"; done; list="${list#,}"; list="${list%,}"; echo $list' -- 1,2 3 4 44 444 1 2
```

Note, though, that most of that line is just getting the list from the arguments and then out to stdout.  Inside a script, `list="${list//,$x,/,}$x,"` is all you need.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo -n "1,2 4 3 2" | awk -v RS='[, ]' '!a[$0]++' | paste -sd,

1,2,4,3
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -le 'undef @h{ (split /,/, shift), @ARGV }; $, = ","; print keys %h' 1,2 4 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a one-liner, but imo still a clean shell solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
list="1,2"
new_items="4 5 3"

for i in $new_items ; do
    # The `\b` does match at word boundaries
    ! grep -Eq "\b$i\b" <<< "$list" && list="$list,$i"
done
echo "$list"
```

If you want a one liner from it, you can put it into a function:

```
function add_items() {
    list="$1"
    new_items="$2"
    for i in $new_items ; do
        ! grep -Eq "\b$i\b" <<< "$list" && list="$list,$i"
    done
    echo "$list"
}
```

Call it like:

```
add_items '1,2' '1 2 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
echo 1,2 3 2 4 | sed -r ':a {s/([^, ]+)(.*)\1/\2,\1/;ta}; s/ /,/g; s/,+/,/g; s/^,//'
```

Comment: `echo 5,4 3 4 5 | sed ...` outputs `,3,4,5`.

Comment: @JamesBrown Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

More AWK:

```
$ cat test.in
1,2 3 2 4
5,4 3 4 5

$ cat test.in|awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ ,]";OFS=","} {delete a; delete b; n=split($0,a,FS); for(i in a) b[a[i]]=n--; for(i in b) printf "%s%s",i,(b[i]>1)?OFS:ORS}'
1,2,3,4
3,4,5
```

Comment: This depends on the index order of `b` corresponding to the index order of `a` w.r.t. printing either `OFS` or `RS`, but that's not always going to be the case. For example, when I call your program with `echo '5,4,3 2 1 5 6' | awk ...` I get `2,3,4,5<\n>6,1,`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't, i get `1,2,3,4,5,6`. I'm running gawn and mawk. What are you on (no pun intended)?

Comment: :-)  Mac OS X with the native bsd awk. With gawk I don't have the problem with my previous example, but it does reproduce with `$ echo '5,4,3 9 8' | gawk ...`.  which gives me `3,4,5,8<\n>9,`.

Answer (score 0):

More and more AWK:

```
$ echo 1,2 3 2 4|awk 'BEGIN {RS="[ ,\n]";OFS=","} {a[$0]=++i} END {for (j in a) printf "%s%s", j, a[j]<NR?OFS:ORS}'
1,2,3,4
```